# How to resolve "The Cluster has some problem" status in GKE Cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have newly started using GKE. I have spinned up a cluster and worked on it actively for a week. To avoid unnecessary billing I have detached billing account from it and hence no resources were active on that account. Now when I need to work again I have attached a billing account with GKE. Now earlier Cluster and components appear to came up but I can see an error at cluster level that says "The cluster has some problem". When I checked under nodes tab in Cluster it shows "Couldn't get data from Cluster". In Compute engine it shows no issue but at Cluster it shows these errors. I thought its taking time to attach node to Cluster tried restarting cluster couple of times . No use . Can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I recommend to [check](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project) if your project linked is linked to your billing account and try to disable and re-enable billing again. Then, check status of your cluster with commands `kubectl cluster-info`, `kubectl get pod -n kube-system`, `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl describe node <node>`. Also, check logs at `Stackdriver` -> `Logging` -> `Logs viewer` for any errors. If you found no errors - try to contact [Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is issue with billing account being attached and detached. It was taking way too long for the same. So if I give it some time it is recovering.

Comment: very cool the cloud console error is so descriptive

Comment: i found myself on this question again after having to google it again. then i see my comment and have deja vu. history repeats